# Cannot figure out how Jump Discontinuity was determined for ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals

I don't know what I'm missing in how the jump discontinuity (the text calls I'm reading calls it the "*jump in the derivative*") in the solution was obtained for the ODE example I am working on, but according to what I was reading, we can find it by simply integrating the inhomogeneous ODE. The issue with that is the result obtained after integrating doesn't make any sense.

I have the ODE:

$$\tag{1}\frac{d^2 a_n(y)}{dy^2}-(\frac{n\pi}{L})^2 a_n(y) = \frac{2}{L}\sin(\frac{n\pi x_0}{L})\delta(y-y_0)$$
where $a_n(y)$ is piecewise and a homogeneous solution for $y<y_0$ and $y>y_0$. In case it helps, here is how it is defined at this point: $a_n(y) = \cases{c \frac{\sinh(\frac{n\pi (y_0-H)}{L})}{\sinh(\frac{n\pi y_0}{L})}\sinh(\frac{n\pi y}{L}) & $y<y_0$\\ c\sinh(\frac{n\pi (y-H)}{L}) & $y>y_0$ }$.

I am told that I can integrate (1) along $dy$ from $y_0^-$ to $y_0^+$ to get the jump in the derivative. So by doing that I get:

$$\tag{2}\frac{n\pi}{L}\Big(\frac{d a_n(y)}{dy}|_{y_0^-}^{y_0^+} - A_n(y)|_{y_0^-}^{y_0^+} \Big) = \frac{2}{L}\sin(\frac{n\pi x_0}{L})$$ where $A_n(y)$ is the antiderivative of $a_n(y)$.

However the text I'm reading instead obtains:
$$\tag{3}\frac{n\pi}{L}\Big(\frac{d a_n(y)}{dy}|_{y_0^-}^{y_0^+}\Big) = \frac{2}{L}\sin(\frac{n\pi x_0}{L})$$.
I have no idea what happened to the $A_n(y)|_{y_0^-}^{y_0^+}$ term nor does the text show or explain what happened to it which has left me completely lost. Does anyone have any ideas as to what might have happened?

---

sidenote: I also noticed that (2) would yield $0 = \frac{2}{L} \sin(\frac{n\pi x_0}{L})$

EDIT: [HERE](https://sv.20file.org/up1/680_0.pdf) is a pdf of the text I was reading from. It starts on 8.5.4 on page 313 (or 326) and on the next page is where we take the jump in the derivative by integrating equation (8.5.13). Jump conditions are discussed at the end of 8.3.4 on page 291 (304 in pdf viewer).

Comment: $$A_n(y)|_{y_0^-}^{y_0^+}=\int_{y_0^-}^{y_0^+}a_n(y)\,dy=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\int_{y_0-\varepsilon}^{y_0+\varepsilon}a_n(y)\,dy=0$$

Comment: Is it $\tag{1}\frac{d^2 a_n(y)}{dx^2}$ or $\tag{1}\frac{d^2 a_n(y)}{dy^2}$?

Comment: @Cesareo The latter. I just fixed it

Comment: @Gonçalo Ah so it *was* included in. Thank you! Is this definitionally true? I'm having some trouble verifying that it is indeed 0. Actually it's more like I'm finding out that I don't actually know the process for integrating this piecewise function. Maybe getting the setup right would help me. Would we split up the integral to integrate each piece such that it would look like $$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \bigg(\int_y^{y_0+\epsilon} a_n(y>y_0)dy  + \int_{y_0-\epsilon}^y a_n(y<y_0)dy \bigg)$$?

Comment: You don't have to compute the integral explicitly in order to compute the limit. Use the fact that $a_n(y)$ is continuous in the interval $[y_0-\epsilon,y_0+\epsilon]$, hence bounded, then use the inequalities 
$$
0\leq\left|\int_{y_0-\epsilon}^{y_0+\epsilon}a_n(y)\,dy\right|\leq
\int_{y_0-\epsilon}^{y_0+\epsilon}|a_n(y)|\,dy \leq
M\int_{y_0-\epsilon}^{y_0+\epsilon}dy=2M\epsilon,
$$
where $M=\max_{y\in[y_0-\epsilon,y_0+\epsilon]}|a_n(y)|$.

Comment: @Gonçalo Alright! And we take the limit as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ which turns the RHS into 0 so it would give $0 \le \text{integral} \le 0$. We know that Green's function (and therefore $a_n(y)$ which is inside $G= \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(y) \phi_n(x)$) MUST be continuous at the singularity point $y = y_0$ as a rule for Green's functions. So this is indeed true. It's also the case that $\frac{dG}{dy}$ is *not* continuous at the singularity point $y = y_0$ and I'll assume this carries over to $a_n(y)$ as well. Is that why the integral of the second order derivative does *not* evaluate to 0?

Comment: Yes, that's right.